# prevent users to navigate back to specific routes with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

I am new to backbone and I want to implement a very simple auth using backbone router.

I am actually using only the router from backbone in my app. When I start the app I render a login view and I also init the backbone router (Backbone.history.start();)

If login succeeded I call `router.navigate('mainmenu', { trigger: true, replace: false });` to navigate to a new route where I render the main menu, but when I click on the browser's back button I navigate back to the login view.

Before navigating to the previous view (the login view) I want to ask the user if he wants to logout first, and if logout process goes well, then he is redirected to the login view.

How can I achieve that? I checked few other questions, but the answer is too complicated for my use case. I just want to prevent users to navigate back to specific views if they're logged in.

Answer (score 2):

@Dethariel thanks for the answer. I successfully implemented some kind of session, using the built-in Backbone router. I started with their small example snippet from the Backbone.Router execute method [backbone router execute snippet](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) and did something similar to bellow:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  // define routes and calkbacks
  // ....
  // define routes and calkbacks

  execute: function(callback, args) {
  // execute will be called before the callback for each specific route
  // get the next route in here
     var nextRoute = Backbone.history.fragment;
     if(user.LoggedIn()){
         // check if nextRoute is '#login*'. I could make other checks as well
         if(nextRoute.indexOf('login')>-1)
             prompt('Log out?');
         // else continue routing
         else if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
     }
     else if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
  }
});
```

This is very minimal, and I don't think it's the best or secure way, but it's a good starting point for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a backbone route which will handle the login page (if you haven't done that yet). Once this route is hit, you do (pseudo-code follows):

```
if (user.isLoggedIn()) {
    if (showLogoutPrompt().decision === "logout") {
        user.logout();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.